# GObject: how to check non-initialized pure virtual at compile time?

Tags: c, gobject

Is there any way in the GObject world to detect uninitialized pure virtual function at compile time?

I'd like to call a pure virtual method without checking it first.

```
/* pure_virtual_method must be non NULL */
base->pure_virtual_method();
```

But if it's not initialized, it will just SegV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t believe there is a way to perfectly check this at compile time, as (for example) your code could be linked into another library, a subclass derived from your class which defines the virtual method, and the implementation of the virtual method set to `NULL` (explicitly, or implicitly through not initialising it) in the subclass.

The conventional way to handle this is at runtime:

`g_assert (base->pure_virtual_method != NULL);
base->pure_virtual_method ();`

Some static analysis tools may be able to check this `g_assert()` constraint at compile time, although given the highly dynamic nature of subclassing in GObject, that’s unlikely.